# Scala: Trait Companion Object is not visible in Java

Tags: java, scala

A companion object for a trait *in Scala* has no visibility problems *in Scala*:

```scala
trait ProtocolPacket extends Serializable {    
  def toByteArray: Array[Byte]
}

object ProtocolPacket {
  def getStreamType( streamBytes: Array[Byte] ) = {
    // ...
  }
}
```

However on Java side (e.g. gets the above in a jar), a `ProtocolPacket.getStreamType` is not visible. In fact a (decompiled by IDEA) source does not have a `getStreamType` method defined for a `ProtocolPacket`

#### EDIT:

I found similar hits on SO regarding `Companion$MODULE$`, but was tricked by IDEA :) as shown below:

[image]

The above compiles and runs fine (shell and/or IDEA itself), in case anybody else gets trapped.

Comment: What does it look like in javap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at `javap` output you will find:

```
$ javap ProtocolPacket
public interface ProtocolPacket extends scala.Serializable{
    public abstract byte[] toByteArray();
}
```

and companion object:

```
$ javap ProtocolPacket$
public final class ProtocolPacket$ extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject,scala.Serializable{
    public static final ProtocolPacket$ MODULE$;
    public static {};
    public void getStreamType(byte[]);
    public java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

this makes me believe in Java you can write:

```
ProtocolPacket$.MODULE$.getStreamType(/**/)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's `ProtocolPacket$.MODULE$.getStreamType()` in Java but I haven't double checked.

See also [How do you call a Scala singleton method from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282653/how-do-you-call-a-scala-singleton-method-from-java).