# Putting object of scala.collection.iterator to the scala class constructor

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

I have a scala class:

**Rts.scala**

```
class Rts(buffer:Iterator[Tse]) extends Ts
{ //Some methods}
```

Now I am trying to put Tse list to the constructor of the above class from java class:

```
Tse tse1= new Tse(1285927200000L, 1285928100000L, 0.0);

Tse tse2 = new Tse(1285928100000L, 1285929000000L, 1.0);

Tse tse3= new Tse(1285929000000L, 1285929900000L, 2.0);

Tse tse4 = new Tse(1285929900000L, 1285930800000L, 3.0);

List<Tse> entryList = new ArrayList<Tse>();
entryList.add(tse1);
entryList.add(tse2);
entryList.add(tse3);
entryList.add(tse4);

Iterator<Tse> iterator = entryList.iterator();
Rts rts= new Rts(iterator); //compile time error
```

**Error Summary:**

```
The constructor Rts(Iterator<Tse>) is undefined
```

What is the right way to put the list to the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala's `scala.collection.Iterator` is not the same type as `java.util.Iterator`. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495741/iterating-over-java-collections-in-scala).

In short, something like the following should work:

```java
new Rts(scala.collection.JavaConversions$.MODULE$.asScalaIterator(iterator));
```

(for calling methods on objects from Java, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282653/how-do-you-call-a-scala-singleton-method-from-java)).

Since this is quite ugly, it's better to define an auxiliary Java API in your Scala library instead. For example:

```scala
class Rts(buffer: Iterator[Tse]) extends Ts {
  // overloaded constructor that can be used from Java
  def this(buffer: java.util.Iterator[Tse]) = this({
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    buffer.asScala
  })
}
```

And then the call should work directly:

```java
new Rts(iterator);
```

---

Otherwise, an *iterator* can only be used once. Are you sure that's what you want? Probably it would be better if you used another collection such as `Seq` or `Iterable`. Again you can find ways to interop with Java in `JavaConverters` and `JavaConversions` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301947/what-is-the-difference-between-javaconverters-and-javaconversions-in-scala) for the difference).

Comment: You can use scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaIterator which is marginally less ugly.